# SwiftUI .onTapGesture issue in TableView with Sections and Rows

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two models:

```
struct Category: Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var number: Int
    var items: [ChecklistItem]
}
```

and:

```
struct ChecklistItem: Identifiable {
  
  let id = UUID()
  var name: String
  var isChecked = false
}
```

with:

```
   class Checklist: ObservableObject {
    
      @Published var items = [Category]()

  func deleteListItem(whichElement: IndexSet) {
    items.remove(atOffsets: whichElement)
  }

  func moveListItem(whichElement: IndexSet, destination: Int) {
    items.move(fromOffsets: whichElement, toOffset: destination)
  }


}
```

I try to implement tap on row to check and uncheck cheklist item in tableView with sections and rows, but I cannot get how this can be released. My code:

```
struct ChecklistView: View {

  @EnvironmentObject var checklist: Checklist
  @State var newChecklistItemViewIsVisible = false

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        ForEach(checklist.items) { category in
            Section(header: Text(category.title)) {
                ForEach(category.items) { item in
                    HStack {
                      Text(item.name)
                      Spacer()
                      Text(item.isChecked ? "✅" : "")
                    }
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if let matchingIndex =
                            category.items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id }) {
                            category.items[matchingIndex].isChecked.toggle()
                      }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        .onDelete(perform: checklist.deleteListItem)
        .onMove(perform: checklist.moveListItem)
      }
      .navigationBarItems(
        leading: Button(action: { self.newChecklistItemViewIsVisible = true }) {
          HStack {
            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
            Text("Add")
          }
        },
        trailing: EditButton()
      )
      .navigationBarTitle("List")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $newChecklistItemViewIsVisible) {
      NewChecklistItemView(checklist: self.checklist)
    }
  }
}
```

I get error with this code on line with category.items[matchingIndex].isChecked.toggle():

```
Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'category' is a 'let' constant
```

How I can get to ChecklistItem and make it check and uncheck on tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI
//Change to class and add NSObject structs are immutable
class Category: NSObject, Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var number: Int
    var items: [ChecklistItem]
    //Now you need an init
    init(title: String , number: Int, items: [ChecklistItem]) {
        self.title = title
        self.number = number
        self.items = items
    }
}
//Change to class and add NSObject structs are immutable
class ChecklistItem: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var isChecked: Bool = false
    //Now you need an init
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
class Checklist: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [Category]()
}
struct ChecklistView: View {
    //Can be an @EnvironmentObject if the @ObservedObject comes from a higher View
    @ObservedObject var checklist: Checklist = Checklist()
    @State var newChecklistItemViewIsVisible = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                
                ForEach(checklist.items) { category in
                    Section(header: Text(category.title)) {
                        ForEach(category.items) { item in
                            Button(action: {
                                print(item.isChecked.description)
                                item.isChecked.toggle()
                                //Something to trigger the view to refresh will not be necessary if using something like @FetchRequest or after you somehow notify `checklist.items` that there is a change
                                checklist.objectWillChange.send()
                            }) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(item.name)
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(item.isChecked ? "✅" : "")
                                }//HStack
                                    //White is incompatible with Text Color in Dark Mode
                                    .background(Color.gray)
                            }//Button
                        }//ForEach
                    }//Section
                }//ForEach
                //Methods not provided
                //.onDelete(perform: checklist.deleteListItem)
                //.onMove(perform: checklist.moveListItem)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: Button(action: {
                    self.newChecklistItemViewIsVisible = true
                    //Code to Add Samples
                    checklist.items.append(Category(title: "Test", number: Int.random(in: 0...100), items: [ChecklistItem(name: "Test")]))
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                        Text("Add")
                    }
                },
                trailing: EditButton()
            )
            .navigationBarTitle("List")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $newChecklistItemViewIsVisible) {
            //Pass as an @EnvironmentObject
            NewChecklistItemView().environmentObject(checklist)
        }
    }
}

struct NewChecklistItemView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var checklist: Checklist
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(checklist.items.count.description)
    }
}
struct ChecklistView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        //When the @ObservedObject comes from a higher View remove comment below
        ChecklistView()//.environmentObject(Checklist())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you also propose how I can intergate move and delete methods to move and delete the checklist item. I added them to my code listing.

Comment: The sample code that Xcode 12 generates with a new project can get you started with that. The big difference would be finding the correct item. I would suggest moving the methods into the 2nd `ForEach` so your `indexSet` refers to the `item` vs `category`. If you have a specific question you can post onto another thread just like you did for this specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting that error is because structs are immutable. You should use method marked with "mutating" inside desired struct. Something like

```swift
if let matchingIndex = category.items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id }) {
    category.items[matchingIndex].toggleItem()
}
```

and inside your struct:

```swift
mutating func toggleItem() {
   self.isChecked.toggle()
}
```

But i would recommend you to use @State instead, because what you are trying to do is straight forward related to how you represent your view. And later, when user is willing to do something with that selection you send that data to your model